# Parsing Line Breaks from Plain Text

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a process that parses emails. The software that we're using to retrieve and store the contents of the body doesn't seem to include line-breaks, so I end up with something like this -

```
Good afternoon, [line-break] this is my email. [line-break] Info: data [line-break] More info: data
```

My [line-break] brackets are where the line breaks ***should*** be. However, when we extract the body, we get just the text. It makes it tough to parse the text without having the line breaks.

Essentially, what I need to do is parse each `[Info]: [Data]`. I can find where the `[Info]` tags begin, but without having line-breaks, I'm struggling to know where the data associated to that info should end. The email is coming from Windows.

Is there any way to take plain text and encode it to some way that would include line breaks?

**Example Email Contents**

`Good Morning,  Order: 1234 The Total: $445 When: 7/10 Type: Dry`

`Good Morning,    Order: 1235  The Total: $1743  Type: Frozen  When: 7/22`

`Order: 1236  The Total: $950.14  Type: DRY  When: 7/10`

`The Total: $514 Order: 1237  Type: Dry  CSR: Tim W`

`Sorry, below is your order:   Order: 1236 The Total: $500 When: 7/10 Type: Dry Creator: Josh A.  Thank you`

Now, I need to loop through the email and parse out the values for Order, Total, and Type. The other placeholder: values are irrelevant and random.

Comment: Are email coming from Windows or Linux?  Linux has a different return which may explain the issue.

Comment: @jdweng Windows.

Comment: Well, are `Info:` and `More info:` constant tags (or elements that show a constant/understandable/predictable pattern)? Are you sure you don't have any *remains* of the original line-breaks (did you parse the byte values)? Cannot you ask to modify the functionality of this program?

Comment: They are constant tags that I'm able to look for in the email. The program we're using isn't our application, so changing the way it extracts it is not an option.

Comment: So, if you have predictable insertion points, can you `IndexOf()` these *placeholders*? Or use a Regex, more useful if you have specific elements in each *placeholder*?

Comment: @Jimi Correct, as of right now I'm using ```IndexOf()``` to identify the starting position of the placeholders. Then, I have to figure out how far to continue parsing to get the data tied to the placeholders. The email isn't in the same format every time.

Comment: Yes, but, after the data of a section ends, you should have another *placeholder* or the end of the string/stream. What's the problem there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217260/discussion-between-james-and-jimi).

Comment: Won't something like: `string pattern = "Order:|The Total:|Type:|Dry When:";
var matches = Regex.Split([Your Email], pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline).Skip(1).ToArray();` do?

Comment: @Jimi The reason that doesn't work is because there could be items that I don't want included in the email. In the example, I don't care about the tag ```When```. If you remove it from the pattern you put, it messes up the value of the last tag ```Type```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
You need to add all possible sections identifiers: it can be updated over time, to add more known identifiers, to reduce the chance of mistakes in parsing the strings.

As of now, if the value marked by a known identifier contains an unknown identifier when the string is parsed, that part is removed.
If an unknown identifier is encountered, it's ignored.

`Regex.Matches` will extract all matching parts, return their Value, the Index position and the length, so it's simple to use `[Input].SubString(Index, NextPosition - Index)` to return the value corresponding to the part requested.

The `EmailParser` class `GetPartValue(string)` returns the content of an identifier by its name (the name can include the colon char or not, e.g. `"Order"` or `"Order:"`).
The `Matches` properties returns a `Dictionary<string, string>` of all matched identifiers and their content. The content is cleaned up - as possible - calling `CleanUpValue()` method.

Adjust this method to deal with some specific/future requirements.

► If you don't pass a Pattern string, a default one is used.
► If you change the Pattern, setting the **`CurrentPatter`** property (perhaps using one stored in the app settings or edited in a GUI or whatever else), the Dictionary of matched values is rebuilt.

Initialize with:

```
string input = "Good Morning,  Order: 1234 The Total: $445 Unknown: some value Type: Dry When: 7/10";
var parser = new EmailParser(input);
string value = parser.GetPartValue("The Total");
var values = parser.Matches;
```

---

```
public class EmailParser
{
    static string m_Pattern = "Order:|The Total:|Type:|Creator:|When:|CSR:";

    public EmailParser(string email) : this(email, null) { }
    public EmailParser(string email, string pattern)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern)) {
            m_Pattern = pattern;
        }
        Email = email;
        this.Matches = GetMatches();
    }

    public string Email { get; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Matches { get; private set; }

    public string CurrentPatter {
        get => m_Pattern;
        set {
            if (value != m_Pattern) {
                m_Pattern = value;
                this.Matches = GetMatches();
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetPartValue(string part)
    {
        if (part[part.Length - 1] != ':') part += ':';
        if (!Matches.Any(m => m.Key.Equals(part))) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Part non included");
        }
        return Matches.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key.Equals(part)).Value;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetMatches()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var matches = Regex.Matches(Email, m_Pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match m in matches) {
            int startPosition = m.Index + m.Length;
            var next = m.NextMatch();
            string parsed = next.Success
                ? Email.Substring(startPosition, next.Index - startPosition).Trim()
                : Email.Substring(startPosition).Trim();

            dict.Add(m.Value, CleanUpValue(parsed));
        }
        return dict;
    }

    private string CleanUpValue(string value)
    {
        int pos = value.IndexOf(':');
        if (pos < 0) return value;
        return value.Substring(0, value.LastIndexOf((char)32, pos));
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I should mark this as the answer because this will definitely help somebody, but I misspoke. When you asked if I knew all of the placeholders, I thought you meant all of the ones that I cared about. I don't know all of the placeholders because it's an email coming from a person. Meaning, they could technically put certain placeholders that I don't care about.

Comment: I posted an example with some terminology replacement. In the example, the pair ```When: 7/10``` represents a placeholder: value that I don't care about and know nothing about. The struggle that this brings is that you don't know when the value of your placeholder ends because you cannot bank on using the "next" match in the regex for a substring.

Comment: posted 2 more examples. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: All those samples have the same *identifiers*: `Order:`, `The Total:`, `When:`, `Type:`. Can this email actually contain other random identifiers? In this case, do these always contain a color? Can there be a colon somewhere else, in the related value, in the email body or whatever? Is this all the text that you actually receive? I can only act on the information you give me...

Comment: I added a few more. There can be random identifiers, yes. All of the identifiers do always contain a colon, and there should never be a colon in the value piece of the string. This is all of the text that I am working with.

Comment: All right, I'll see whether it's possible to generate sections of these samples consistently. I'll let you know.

Comment: I gave the parser a twist, it's a little smarter and more *configurable*. Try it out. -- I don't see other way to make it less prone to (partial) failure than *training* it. The simpler way is to adjust the patter recognition (adding more *identifiers* as these become available/known). Otherwise, you need proper training, as in machine learning (which requires *storage facilities*), so it can rebuild the pattern on its own.

Comment: In this case, the `Dictionary<string, string>` could be replaced by a `List<class>` objects, where the object can provide means to acknowledge a failure, ask for the correct match (maybe just moving the pattern it failed to recognize one or more *words* to the left), so it can register the correct sequence.

Comment: This is incredible. You're a beast.